# Mailchimp Opt-In Confirmation CSS

Tags: html, css, outlook, mailchimp, newsletter

I have a problem with the Mailchimp Opt-in confirmation email in Outlook.
I just want to center the Subscribe button at the end of the Newsletter and it should have a red background with white text.

It´s not possible to add a style on the a-Tag.

See the Code below:

```
<a class="button" href="foo"><span>SUBSCRIBE</span></a>
```

Update: Its also not possible to change the html in Mailchimp ...

I tried to add the styles with inline css, but that didn´t worked out.

Has someone a hint for me?

Comment: try this: `<center><a style='' href='foo'>subscribe</a></center>`

Comment: what do you mean by "it is not possible to change the html in mailchimp"? you can't modify your template?

Comment: What inline styles did you try? try: `display: inline-block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;`

Comment: The link is generated by Mailchimp. Mailchimp offers two flieds to change the background and the text color. The Template has 3 editable flieds with a texteditor like this:

Head - editable
Content - editable
Subscribe Button - Text is ediable
Foot - editable

Comment: Thank you @MarkWilson! This CSS worked for me!

Comment: You are welcome @VZimmerl. Glad I could help. I posted the ruels in the answer since it worked for you. Have a great day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following rules to your button. It will make sure to make the button inline-block level element and the margin-left and right auto will bring the button to center.

```
display: inline-block; 
margin-left: auto; 
margin-right: auto;
```